# How can I disable a QCheckBox WITHOUT triggering an event?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcheckbox

I am wondering if there is anyway to disable (setCheckState) on a check box (QCheckBox) in pyqt "WITHOUT" triggering an event? So it is simply a display change with the checkbox now unticked but not triggering the method I have it connected to. Thanks for any help.

Would love a basic example if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply block signals just before disabling the QCheckBox, and
re-enabling them just after. Assuming `chk` is your QCheckBox
object just do:

```
chk.blockSignals()
# then you change the checkbox as you want
chk.unblockSignals()
```

Comment: The big downside of `blockSignals()` is that it blocks *all* signals for the widget - including the ones Qt connects to internally. This can sometimes make it a bit of bug trap, due to unexpected side-effects.

Comment: @ekhumoro ...good to know. It's fine for my purposes because I literally enable directly after I uncheck. However, would be keen to hear your alternative? It seems like a scenario that would be often useful ...manipulate the ui without triggering events.

Comment: @NickvanDiem. Although my comment is broadly true, at the time I made it I was certain I had a simpler alternative. But it seems my memory was playing tricks on me, and that turns out not to be the case. The only real alternative I can think of now is to disconnect and reconnect the signal - which is certainly safer, but not as simple.

Comment: @ekhumoro ...no problems. Thanks very much for pondering on it :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @mguijarr says it all, but apparently they changed the function a bit.

In QT 5.14.0 it is:

```
chk.blockSignals(True)
chk.blockSignals(False)
# same syntax for c++ and py at this place
```

[docs for python](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-dev/PySide2/QtCore/QObject.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QObject.blockSignals)

[docs for c++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals)

(Maybe this would better be a comment, but I need more rep for comments)

Comment: In which part of the docs does it indicate that unblockSignals can be used? I do not see that anything has changed regarding this method.

Comment: it was already too late yesterday... I wanted to correct the outdated information but just repeated the second statement. I fixed it.